# Does #Requires work in module scripts?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

Consider the following module script:

#### `MyWebApp.psm1`:

```
#Requires -Version 4
#Requires -Modules WebAdministration

function Test-MyWebApp() {
    return ((Get-WebApplication 'myapp') -ne $null)
}
```

(`Export-ModuleMember` omitted for simplicity. The script still works as a module without it.)

If this were a `ps1` script, the `#Requires` comments at the top would force PowerShell to throw an error if

- The version were lower than 4
- The WebAdministration module could not be loaded (imported)

But if I try to import this using `Import-Module`, do these have any effect? [The `#Requires` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires) just says "scripts", but it doesn't clarify whether script modules count as "scripts" or not here. What can I do instead, if not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### No, it's treated as a normal comment

No, `#Requires` comments are not processed when a `psm1` script is executed by calling `Import-Module`.

If we save the script in the question as both `MyWebApp.psm1` and `MyWebApp.ps1` on a machine that lacks the `WebAdministration` module, we get the following result:

```
PS> .\MyWebApp.ps1
.\MyWebApp.ps1 : The script 'MyWebApp.ps1' cannot be run because the following modules that are specified by the
"#requires" statements of the script are missing: WebAdministration.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\MyWebApp.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (MyWebApp.ps1:String) [], ScriptRequiresException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptRequiresMissingModules

PS> Import-Module .\MyWebApp.psm1
PS>
```

Importing the module succeeds, and the function now exists in the current scope. But the function will fail:

```
PS> Test-MyWebApp
Get-WebApplication : The term 'Get-WebApplication' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At .\MyWebApp.psm1:5 char:14
+     return ((Get-WebApplication 'myapp') -Eq $null)
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-WebApplication:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Even the `-Version` check is ignored. If we bump it up to 5 on a machine with only PowerShell 4:

```
PS> .\MyWebApp.ps1
.\MyWebApp.ps1 : The script 'MyWebApp.ps1' cannot be run because it contained a "#requires" statement for Windows
PowerShell 5.0. The version of Windows PowerShell that is required by the script does not match the currently running
version of Windows PowerShell 4.0.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\MyWebApp.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (MyWebApp.ps1:String) [], ScriptRequiresException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptRequiresUnmatchedPSVersion

PS> Import-Module .\MyWebApp.psm1
PS>
```

#### Use a Module Manifest

The only way to get the requirements validated properly is to use a [module manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd878337.aspx). Unfortunately, this must be a separate file alongside the `psm1` file. The following manifest will achieve what the `#Requires` comments are intended to do:

**`MyWebApp.psd1`:**

```
#
# Module manifest for module 'MyWebApp'
#

@{
ModuleVersion = '1.0'
PowerShellVersion = '4.0'
RequiredModules = @('WebAdministration')
RootModule = @('.\MyWebApp.psm1')
}
```

Importing this file gives the error we want:

```
PS> Import-Module .\MyWebApp.psd1
Import-Module : The required module 'WebAdministration' is not loaded. Load the module or remove the module from 'RequiredModules' in the file 
'.\MyWebApp.psd1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module .\MyWebApp.psd1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (.\MyWebApp.psd1:String) [Import-Module], MissingMemberException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidManifest,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Unfortunately, you cannot declare the function in the same file. You must use a *separate* `psd1` file and then explicitly declare the original `psm1` script as the "root module." The root module is indicated as a *path* relative to the `psd1` file.

Other attributes:

- The `ModuleVersion` is required. It must be present.
- `PowerShellVersion` accomplishes what `#Requires -Version 4` intends.
- `RequiredModules` accomplishes what `#Requires -Modules WebAdministration` intends.

Note that `Test-MyWebApp` is exported implicitly in both the `psm1` and the `psd1` file. This is normally controlled by `Export-ModuleMember -Function` in a `psm1` file; the equivalent in a module manifest is `FunctionsToExport`. I find it simpler to just omit `FunctionsToExport` from the manifest and control what's exported using `Export-ModuleMember` in the `psm1` script.